# Unhashable type error whenever using an edited pdf and PyPdf

Tags: python, pdf, typeerror, pypdf

I am trying to arrange pdf pages in a specific order, an I need to add a blank page to the end of my pdf prior to doing that(to make the pages even).

However, while my code works fine on the original pdf, I get a type error once I add the blank page. The first 3 pages seem unaffected (reader.pages[2] works, but not reader.pages[3]). Can anyone please explain why this is and how to solve it?

Here is my current code:

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PageObject
import shutil

my_pdf = "pdf_name.pdf"
changefile = PdfWriter()
num_pg = len(reader.pages)
```

```
def insert_b_page(org_pdf):
    a = open(org_pdf, 'rb')
    pdf=PyPDF2.PdfReader(a)
    numPages=len(pdf.pages)
    outPdf=PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
    outPdf.append_pages_from_reader(pdf)
    outPdf.add_blank_page()
    outStream=open('amended.pdf','wb')
    outPdf.write(outStream)
    outStream.close()
    a.close()
    #Copy amended file back over the original
    shutil.copyfile('amended.pdf',org_pdf)

if num_pg =! 0:
    insert_p_page(my_pdf)

reader = PdfReader(my_pdf)

for n in range(0, num_pg//2,2):
    changefile.add_page(reader.pages[num_pg-(n+1)])
    changefile.add_page(reader.pages[n])
```

Comment: Please show the stack backtrace.